# Android - how can an Activity get user entered text from a Dialog

Tags: android, dialog

I thought this would be easy but its eluding me.  I have an Activity that displays a custom dialog that allows the user to enter some text and then has OK and Cancel button defined.  I display it using show().  But I can't figure out how to get the value back from the Dialog.

I'm using a custom dialog because its doing some validation of the text entry.  I guess I could change it to derive from Activity and then display it using startActivityForResult but - at least based on my old windows programming days - I thought getting a user entered value back from an Android dialog would be easy.

Am I overlooking some type of call back or listener mechanism?

I even tried this as a simple solution but its not letting me assign to value (1) unless its modifier is set to final and then (2) if I say ok to make it final, won't let me assign to it because "the final local variable value cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type"

```
    String value;

    final EditText input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.theText); 

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setView(input);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) 
        {
            value = input.getText().toString();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    builder.show();
```

[EDIT updated for solution]============================

The main thing I ended up doing was adding the ability to pass a Handler to the dialog.  In the dialog class I added:

```
   private Handler clientHandler = null;

   public void AddHandler(Handler client)
   {
      this.clientHandler = client;
   }
```

And updated the Dialog's OK button click:

```
   /**
    * The user pressed the OK button
    * @param v
    */
   public void okClick(View v)
   {
      // save the entered string
      this.tag = this.tagEditText.getText().toString();

      if ( null != this.clientHandler )
      {
         // Notify the client to update itself
         this.clientHandler.sendMessage( clientHandler.obtainMessage());
      }

      cancel();
   }
```

Then in the Activity's onCreate() that displays the Dialog I added:

```
 tagDialog = new tagDialog(this); 

 tagHandler = new Handler() 
 {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
    {
       tag = tagDialog.tag;               
    }
 };

 tagDialog.AddHandler(tagHandler);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to send a Message to a Handler. Use obtainMessage() to get the
Message object, Then send the Message to the Handler via its message queue.

Comment: These have all been great suggestions, but this one is the one that got me going down the right path to solve my issue.  I guess it turns out that its just not as easy to get the data from a dialog as I hoped.  I'll post code from my final solution.  Thank you everyone

Answer (score 2):

Save stuff you want to save in `onClickListener` of your `Dialog`. Use `dialog.findViewById()` to find your text box, save the text somewhere (or use Handler) and then in Activity retrieve the saved text.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm missing something here, won't a static String do?

Comment: yup it did for my case. But the variable has to declared at the top in class. Is there anyway a local variable can be used for assignment?